# Process music being played by another Android app?

Tags: android

I'm looking to make an Android app that can process music being played by another app. More specifically I want to analyze the raw audio. I've done some research and looked around, but I'm beginning to think this isn't possible, and maybe for good reason.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to achieve this capability?

Comment: Do you need/want a solution that works for non-rooted devices?

Comment: Yes. I was hoping to make an app anyone can use. But, it may be worth considering the rooted route. Do you have a solution for the rooted case?

Comment: No, although I'm guessing a solution is possible for rooted devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your requirement is to analyse  all aps audio and want to process raw audio too.only one possibility is there which is to start recorder in background service and analyse audio all the time like many of the call recorder app on play store is doing to record a call.

it does have some drawbacks too

1. background noise
2. you will not able to know when music starts and when stops.

Comment: "start recorder" - you mean the voice recorder that uses the microphone? That sounds like a very bad idea, will give very poor quality, or if the person is listening to music with earphones it won't record anything.

Comment: I know its bad idea but this is only way for right now as we cant capture sound globally from device.

Comment: Yeah. I had thought of this possibility, but like both of you said, it's very limiting. Thanks for the answer! Looks like I'll have to settle for a limited solution.